# Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'int' for comparing 2 variables

Tags: c#

Im having an issue whereby the variables to check if the random number and user input variables are the same. This is required to check if they have the same value as I need it for the game mastermind I am creating as a college project. Thanks.

```
 public void DrawStart()
    {
        Console.Clear();
        Random rnd = new Random();
        int numberOne = rnd.Next(1, 7); //This is generating a random number and is saving it within the variable numberOne
        int numberTwo = rnd.Next(1, 7); //This is generating a random number and is saving it within the variable numberTwo
        int numberThree = rnd.Next(1, 7); //This is generating a random number and is saving it within the variable numberThree
        int numberFour = rnd.Next(1, 7); //This is generating a random number and is saving it within the variable numberFour
        Console.WriteLine("This is your first guess.");
        Console.WriteLine("Good luck");
        string gnumberOne = Console.ReadKey().KeyChar.ToString();
        string gnumberTwo = Console.ReadKey().KeyChar.ToString();
        string gnumberThree = Console.ReadKey().KeyChar.ToString();
        string gnumberFour = Console.ReadKey().KeyChar.ToString();
        Console.WriteLine("");
        Console.WriteLine("These are the random numbers");
        Console.Write(numberOne);
        Console.Write(numberTwo);
        Console.Write(numberThree);
        Console.Write(numberFour);
        if (numberOne = gnumberOne)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("X");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("O");
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }-
```

Comment: You try to compare string with int. Use int.Parse to convert the user input to an integer and the you can compare the value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to parse the string

```
if (numberOne == int.Parse(gnumberOne))
{
    Console.WriteLine("X");
}
```

And you should be using `==` to compare not `=`

You might want to take a look at [TryParse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7(v=vs.110).aspx) to safely parse your numbers without the application crashing if someone would enter something else than a number.

Comment: @BenReilly Happy I could help :)

Comment: @BenReilly Make sure to mark this as the answer if you are satisfied with the result

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, you need to use `==` in your if statement to compare two values. `=` assigns values, it doesn't do comparison.

Your line `if (numberOne == gnumberOne)` is comparing an int to a string. You need to compare like to like.
Try:

```
if (numberOne.ToString() == gnumberOne)
```

or

```
if (numberOne == int.Parse(gnumberOne))
```